# AVL Tree Rotation Child Attaching Error

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I know already AVL Tree in theory but I can't put it into codes. I'm already able to do right and left rotations for right left and left right cases. But I can't do the rotations for left left and right right cases. Here's the one for the left rotate.

```
void leftRotate(AVLNode **rootptr){

AVLNode *temp1, *temp2;

if(rootptr!=NULL && *rootptr!=NULL && (*rootptr)->right!=NULL){
    temp1 = *rootptr;
    if(temp1->parent->left == temp1 && temp1->right != NULL) {
        temp1->right->parent = temp1->parent;
        temp1->parent->left = temp1->right;

        temp1->parent = temp1->right;
        temp1->right->left = temp1;
        temp1->left = temp1->right = NULL;
        temp1 = temp1->parent;
    }else{
        temp2 = temp1->parent;
        if(temp1->parent->parent == NULL){
            temp1->parent->parent = temp1;
            temp1->parent->right = temp1->left;
            temp1->left = temp1->parent;
            temp1->parent = NULL;
        }

    }   
    updateHeight(temp1->left);
    updateHeight(temp1);
}
}
```

The else part is for right right case. The line that keeps giving me a status access violation error is this part. It's supposed to put the pivot parent into its left child

```
temp1->left = temp1->parent;
```

I've checked it, temp1->left is NULL, temp1->parent exists but I can't seem to put it into the tree. If I erase that part, it works but of course I'm missing temp1's left child.

Comment: Anybody? I need to answer this quickly.

Comment: I don't anything about AVL Trees so I don't know what type left, parent etc are supposed to be. Can you include the definitions?

Comment: How can you answer the question then? An AVL tree is like a binary tree but it has a condition that the difference of their children's height should not be greater than 1.

Comment: Nobody else was answering it so I thought I would give it a go, but I guess not.